# Changing the text color in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, textcolor

I am using an MPMoviePlayerController and the nav bar that shows the progress slider, along with the time elapsed to the left and right. My nav bar is a very light grey, so I'd like to change the color of the text from white to dark grey.

How do I change the default text color in the MPMoviePlayerController?

EDIT: I have tried creating an appearance property for it, but it seems unable to take that.

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: cantread]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [appearance delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) to change various attributes of various classes, including the text color.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController seems unable to use the appearance delegate. I tried this code where my other appearance functions are set, yet it does not work - [[UINavigationBar appearance]       setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Re-reading your question, that text must be in a custom view. It might be the title view or it could be a custom sub view. You'd need to write some code to get the view, inspect the subviews and change the text color of any labels you find.